# What is the predefined order in which man searches sections?

Tags: man, gnu

The description of `man` in its [own man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html) contains the statement,

> The default action is to search in all of the
>          available sections following a pre-defined order ("1 n l 8 3 0 2 5 4
>          9 6 7" by default, unless overridden by the SECTION directive in
>          /usr/local/etc/man_db.conf), and to show only the first page found,
>          even if page exists in several sections.

What exactly is meant by *"1 n l 8 3 0 2 5 4 9 6 7"*?

Comment: The man page of my Windows 10 Ubuntu man is even more confusing than the one posted above:
"1 n l 8 3 2 3posix 3pm 3perl 3am  5 4  9  6 7"

Comment: On a side note, you can set your own search order with `export MANSECT=0p:1:2:3:3p:4:5:6:7:8:9:l:s:n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the "section" of the `man`-page - that number in parenthesis following the name, for example `ls(1)`.

You could think of the man-pages as a set of actual manuals, divided into several volumes.  For example, the 1st "volume" is section 1 which contains ordinary user commands - like ls(1), bash(1) and man(1).  Section 8 contains commands for the system administrator - like commands for shutting down the system and install packages.  (often commands that can't be used by non-root users.)  Section 5 contains file-formats - like how /etc/passwd and /etc/sudo should be formatted.  Section 3 contains library-functions for various languages (mostly for C) - like the C-function printf().

Note that some "commands" - like `cd` and `fg` - are really so-called built-ins in the shell, and don't have their own man-page.  Instead they're documented in the man-pages for the particular shell - eg. in the man-page of bash(1).  Shells may also provide alternatives to some commands as built-ins, and will usually use these instead of the external command.  One example is how bash(1) got a built-in version of kill(1).

From the man-page of man-pages(7):

```
   1   Executable programs or shell commands
   2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
   3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
   4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
   5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
   6   Games
   7   Miscellaneous (including macro packages and conventions), e.g.
       man(7), groff(7)
   8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
   9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
```

Sometimes letters or words are added to the number to denote the man-page belongs to a sub-system or package, for example, "x" for X GUI commands like startx(1x), or "tcl" for commands and functions belonging to the Tcl-language.  Or even that they're "optional"/"additional" or "alternative" commands - for example, if you got two versions of `tar`, one from GNU and one from BSD.

To get a specific section, you can add the section-number to your man-command:

`man passwd` returns the passwd-command from section 1 (because section 1 is searched first, and the search then stops)

`man 1 passwd` returns the same (but now because we specified section 1)

`man 5 passwd` returns the file-format of /etc/passwd from section 5 (because we specified section 5 instead of 1)

To differentiate the two, you would refer to them as passwd(1) and passwd(5) (eg. if you wrote a textbook - or a man-page).

So the search-order makes sense - commands are more often sought than file-formats, not to mention programming libraries and system-calls.

Finally, you should note that different Unix-systems may use slightly different sectioning, for example, I've seen section 7 used for word-processing commands, and section 9 used for games, and I've seen section 9 used as a catch-all for various man-pages not fitting elsewhere.